# Add ASP.NET Identity (User Management) to OData via Web API 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I have an OData project that was created from Web API template (including credentials).

I have an ApplicationUser:IdentityUser class.

I have a TournamentContext : IdentityDbContext class.

I have the default AccountController that comes with the template with [RoutePrefix("api/Account")] attribute.

In WebApiConfig.cs
For the web api template default routing I have

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

For the OData support I've added:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetModel(),
            new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

and

```
private static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();            
        builder.EntitySet<Tournament>("Tournaments");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Now,
I want to expose the account/user management via the OData API.
How do I achieve that?

Thanks,
Janiv Ratson.

Comment: Are you trying to do this while still also keeping the api path?

Comment: Yes, but I can give it up.

Answer (score 4):

You can create ODataController for managing user identities using scaffolding:

1) right mouse click on Controllers folder, Add -> Controller...

2) choose "Web API 2 OData Controller with actions, Entity Framework"

3) in a dialog select generated model class for app users - ApplicationUser (WebApplication1.Models) by default - and appropriate data context

4) after generation is done you should replace DbSet property declaration automatically added to your data context

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

with method declaration

```
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> GetApplicationUsers()
    {
        return (DbSet<ApplicationUser>) Users;
    }
```

(because your data context is iherited from IdentityDbContext, which has IDbSet Users property). So there's error

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'

unless you do the replacement.

5) last - you should replace in generated controller code "db.ApplicationUsers" to "db.GetApplicationUsers()".